# Devolver un Array<object> con REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy obteniendo los datos de un fichero JSON con la información y he creado una función para obtener los datos de dicho fichero JSON. Hasta aquí bien, pero quiero poner estos datos en un DataGrid de MUI, que me pide rows y columns, las columnas las puse a mano pero los rows quiero rellenarlo automáticamente con los datos que obtengo del fichero JSON.

Código función:

```
function Productos() {
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const getData = () => {
  fetch("dadesBD.json", {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      //console.log(response);
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (myJson) {
      // console.log(myJson);
      setData(myJson);
    });
};
useEffect(() => {
  getData();
}, []);

return (
 
    {data && data.length > 0 && data.map((item) => (
           ` 
           id:${item.id}
           nombre:${item.nombre}      
           `
      ))}
    
  
);
```

}

Lo que quiero llegar a conseguir es una const así:

```
const rows = [
{
  id: 1,
  nombre: "Jose",
},];
```

Para poder pasarle al componente:

```
<DataGrid
    rows={rows}
    columns={columns}
    pageSize={5}
    rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
    checkboxSelection
    disableSelectionOnClick
  />
```

Comment: Podes agregar un ejemplo de la data que contiene `dadesBD.json`?

Comment: [
    {
    1,
    "Jose",
    },  {
    2,
    "Juan",
    },]

Comment: Si ya estas recibiendo los items con ese formato, es decir, que el array contiene objectos así: `{ id: 1, nombre: "Jose"}` y las columnas del Grid se llaman de la misma manera, no tiene porque hacerle el `.map()`.

Comment: Mira este ejemplo: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-datagrid-s2eyd?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo solucione! Dejo mi ejemplo por si alguien le sirve de ayuda

https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-wilbur-hpx48?file=/src/components/EjemploFetch/FetchDB.js